# Terminology and properties on $f$ and $g$ such that $g(f(x))=x$ for all $x$.

Tags: general-topology, functions, metric-spaces

Let $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$ be both continuous and such that $g(f(x))=x$, for all $x\in A$, where $A$ and $B$ are metric spaces.

1. Is $g$ the inverse function of $f$?
2. Is $f$ a bijective mapping?
3. Do $A$ and $B$ have the same topological properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Let A = {0}, B = {0,1}, f(0) = 0 and g map B to {0}.

Comment: Ok, thank you. If I add the requirement $f(g(y))=y$ for all $y\in B$, would the questions have a positive answer?

Comment: @user52227.  Yes.